# how to compare a variable with a serial numbers list?

Tags: php

i want to know if a var content equals one of serial numbers in .txt file
and how to be sure that the var equals the serial number(**just one line**) exactly

some of serial numbers

```
07049588
41065617
70126500
18271021
09513492
06841361
```

Comment: So `is_serial('70126500')` should return true while `is_serial('1010101')` should return false?

Comment: i have no code i just want to know how

Comment: [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents), [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) and [in_array](http://www.php.net/in_array) are your friends.

Comment: @ccKep [Exactly what I was thinking](https://eval.in/private/3e2663964a8d0d).

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it you are looking for the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function. It finds a needle in a haystack.

I am not sure what your data source is so I shall assume like the other answer  that it is a flat file.

```
<?php
$serials = file_get_contents("serials.txt");
$haystack = explode(" ", $serials);
$needle = "70126500";

if(in_array($needle, $haystack))
{
    print "Found ".$needle."!";
}
else
{
    print "Could not find ".$needle."!";
}
?>
```

Easier that going over an array every time.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, get the file content and explode them using whitespaces then loop all to find which matches the serial then echo it

```
<?php 
$content = file_get_contents( 'filepath.txt' );
$content = explode( ' ', $content );
$searching_serial  =  70126500;

if( $content ) {
    foreach( $content as $serial ) {
        if( $serial == $searching_serial ) {
            echo 'This matches ' . $serial;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OPs question suggests he has newlines in his file, so I'd throw [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) in the mix just to be sure, also: `in_array($searching_serial, $content)` looks more readable to me and should be a bit quicker on large arrays than looping yourself.